# Dagger component not found error in Java?

Tags: java, dagger

```
public class ToInject {
    public int val = 0;

    public ToInject(){
        System.out.println("Default");
    }
}
```

```
@Module
public class ToInjectModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ToInject provideToInject(){
        return new ToInject();
    }
}
```

```
@Component(modules = ToInjectModule.class)
public interface ToInjectModuleComponent {
    WillGetInjected willGetInjectedMaker();
}
```

```
public class WillGetInjected {
    private ToInject toInject;
    @Inject
    public WillGetInjected(ToInject toInject){
        this.toInject = toInject;
        System.out.println(this.toInject.val);
    }
}
```

I am trying to inject `ToInject` into `WillGetInjected` as you see above. I have a `ToInjectModule` and als a `ToInjectModuleComponent` so I am following the instructions fully completely. I have also imported

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

But I keep getting this error when I do `mvn compile`:

```
Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/Subcomponent$Builder: dagger.Subcomponent$Builder -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea what is happening and why?

Comment: Perhaps you should post your entire POM file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two missings.

1. Add `dagger compiler` into `pom.xml`  ([Link](https://github.com/google/dagger#maven))

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
          <path>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.x</version>
          </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

2. Add `annotation scope` into component. ([Link](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide) see `Singletons and Scoped Bindings`)

```
@Component(modules = ToInjectModule.class)
public interface ToInjectModuleComponent {
    WillGetInjected willGetInjectedMaker();
}
```

to

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ToInjectModule.class)
public interface ToInjectModuleComponent {
    WillGetInjected willGetInjectedMaker();
}
```